# Proving that two norms are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the two norms $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ on $C[0,1] = \{f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} | f\text{ is continuous}\}$ defined by
$$
||f||_1 = \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|dt, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ||f||_{\infty} = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)|
$$
respectively, $\forall f \in C[0,1]$. Define the map $||\cdot||$ by
$$
||f|| = ||f||_1 + ||f||_{\infty}
$$
Prove that $||f||$ is equivalent to $||f||_{\infty}$

---

So I want to find $c_1,c_2 > 0$ such that

$$
c_1 \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)| \leq \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|dt + \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)| \leq c_2 \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)|
$$

The first inequality I am able to show for $c_1 = 1$ it is clear that

$$
c_1 \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)| \leq \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|dt + \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)| \\
\iff \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)| \leq \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|dt + \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)|
$$

Which is true because $\int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|dt > 0$, $\forall f \in C[0,1] \backslash \{0\}$.

But I'm stuck here, I don't know how to go about finding $c_2$. We haven't been shown any examples in my course so far and I'm struggling to find any.

Comment: Hint: you have $|f(t)| \leq \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|$. This may be obvious, but how can you make use of this here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\int_0^1 |f(t)| dt\leq (1-0)\sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)|=||f||_{\infty}$. You can then see how $c_2=2$.